# IOS: app universal concepts

Tags: ios, ios-universal-app

I'm starting a project that must be for iPhone and iPad...you can tell me that it's easy and that I can create an "Universal" project..it's right.
But I have a "stupid" question about a "stupid" problem.
In an universal project I have two .xib (iPhone and iPad) for a class and inside code I verify if I'm using the one or the other

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
     // The device is an iPad running iPhone 3.2 or later.
}
else
{
     // The device is an iPhone or iPod touch.
}
```

ok?

But you know that in a single view of iPad I can show many views that an iPhone can show one at time.
At example I have two view with their classes:

```
FirstView.h-FirstView.m-FirstView_iPad.xib-FirstView_iPhone.xib
```

and

```
SecondView.h-SecondView.m-SecondView_iPad.xib-SecondView_iPhone.xib
```

For iPhone it's not a problem but for iPad? In a view in iPad I can put first and second viewcontroller, it's not easy to organize if I have two different classes for two viewcontrollers... Do you have a solution for this? Or the best solution is crate two separate project iPhone and iPad?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

So yeah I always use one theViewController.h and one theViewController.m and I have a theViewController.xib for iPhone and a separate xib for iPad only. if you name the iPad xib ending with theViewController~ipad.xib the OS will automatically recognise the XIB. You will have to set the class of the theViewController~ipad.xib in Interface builder in the inspector area to the same class as your iphone xib i.e the class would be called theViewController then you can connect up what ever outlets you have defined in your .h and .m also the great thing about just naming the iPad xib to ending with ~ipad.xib when you push views you dont have to check the idom before pushing as the OS recognises the ~ipad.xib extension and pushes the correct view depending on device..hopefully this is helpful for you!

Comment: thanks but it's not my problem... I asked for a problem of incompatibility between iphone view and ipad view, because inside an ipad view I can have more view of iphone, do you understand?